# How to Convert the JS array to VB Script array (2-D array)

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am working in classic asp.
Can any one give me a demo for **how to convert the Java script array to VB Script array**.(with 2-D arrays)

Thanks,
Jagadi.

Comment: You mean pass them back and forth between Javascript and VB?

Comment: Do you mean between client side Javascript and server side VB Script? or between server side JScript and server side VB Script? Maybe you could expand the question and tell us more about what you're doing and flag to re-open.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your question, you're just looking for examples in both languages?

**Javascript Examples**

```
var jsArray = new Array();
jsArray[0] = new Array();
jsArray[0][0] = "word";
jsArray[0][1] = "definition";
```

```
var jsArray = new Array(new Array("word","def"), new Array("word2","def2"));
document.write(jsArray[0][0] + ": " + jsArray[0][1]);
```

```
var jsArray = [["word","def"],["word2","def2"]];
```

```
var jsArray = "word|definition".split("|");
document.write(jsArray[0] + ": " + jsArray[1]);
```

```
var jsArray = new Array();
jsArray[0] = "word|definition".split("|");
document.write(jsArray[0][0] + ": " + jsArray[0][1]);
```

**Visual Basic Examples**

```vb
Dim vbArray(0 to 1) As String
vbArray(0) = Split("word|definition","|")
```

```vb
Dim vbArray(0 to 1, 0 to 1) As String
vbArray(0,0) = "word"
vbArray(0,1) = "definition"
' I can't remember if the this next assignment type works or not, and I'm on Linux so I can't test it right now. If someone can verify?...
vbArray(1)(0) = "word"
vbArray(1)(1) = "definition"
```

[More information on multidimensional arrays in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02e7z943%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[More information on multidimensional arrays in Javascript](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/multidimensional-arrays-in-javascript/6310694)

Comment: Hi..druciferre,  where we have to use the jsArray[i][j], Can I use at the Split() function?

Comment: Yes, but you don't use `split()` in Javascript the same way you do in Visual Basic. I added an example of using `split()` in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks druciferre, Can you Provid me one example which will show : how to convert any javascritp(2_D) array into vbscript array. In above Example, you are spiting the string. but i want to use there as a JSarray directly. Is this posible? with out split().

Comment: Are you asking for a program/script that you copy and paste the source of a JS array into and it output the array converted to VB?

Comment: 1)Yes, Actually i am having one sub in this i am having one array (i can say it as VBScript 2_d array). 2) I am having one dropdown list. Now what i have to do, I need to call one function into dropdown list which will call javadcript function, Here i need to convert this VB to JS and after that using this JS array, i want to re-initialize my VB array from javascript array.